# Unable to display the messages received on UI when using System.net.Sockets connection

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I am new to xamarin.forms. I want to build a xamarin forms app that can receive messages using System.net.Sockets. My problem is that I am able to receive messages but unable to make the messages displaying on the UI.

I am using dependency service, so I implemented the socket method on every platform specifically, this is my socket receive method in the Android project. I am trying to use messaging center to send the data from android project to the PCL project. IResource is a class I defined in PCL.

```
class SocketConnection : ISocket
{
Socket sSocket;
Socket serverSocket;

public void ReceiveMessage()
{
    Int32 port = 7777;


    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.100");
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);

    sSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sSocket.Bind(ipe);
    sSocket.Listen(0);

    //receive message
    serverSocket = sSocket.Accept();
    Console.WriteLine("connection succeeded");

    while (true)
       {
           byte[] recByte = new byte[4096];
         int bytes = serverSocket.Receive(recByte, recByte.Length, 0);
            IResource.data1+=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recByte, 0, bytes);

         MessagingCenter.Send<ISocket, string>(this,"new Messages",IResource.data1);

        Console.WriteLine("client: " + IResource.data1);

           //send message
           if (IResource.data1.Equals("exit"))
           {
               break;
           }
       }

     serverSocket.Close();
     sSocket.Close();

}
}
```

And in my pcl project, I have a button, when this button is clicked it will use call the ReceiveMessage() method. And I also used the messaging center to receive the messages and display it on UI, but it didn't work out. this is the method for the button click. does anyone know where is the problem, is that i am not using messaging center correctly, or something else. plus: when the button is clicked, the UI becomes unresponsive, should I use asynchronous programming? and how?

Thanks in advance!

```
private async void Yes_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ISocket,string>(this,"new Messages", (socket, data) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            editor.IsVisible = true;
            editor.Text = data;

        });
    });
    DependencyService.Get<ISocket>().ReceiveMessage();  


}
```

Comment: are you sure that MessagingCenter is receiving the messages?  You might want to subscribe BEFORE you call your socket code?

Comment: Please note that you must comply to the `MessagingCenter<Subscriber Type, Message Type>`  in order for it to work properly. Make sure the class where `Yes_Clicked` is declared, have the same type or implements the interface

Comment: I think MessagingCenter< Sender type, Message Type>  only cares about the sender type, any class in the project should be able to subscribe to this message without being the same type or implementing the interface @mr5

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I should put the subscribe method before my socket code, and the main reason is that my socket method is blocking my UI thread, and after I set up a new thread for my socket code the UI become responsive and can display messages.  @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where is the problem, is that i am not using messaging center correctly, or something else. plus: when the button is clicked, the UI becomes unresponsive, should I use asynchronous programming?

You are blocking the UI thread by using while loop. You need to start a new Thread if you want the UI to be responsive:

```
Thread thread = new Java.Lang.Thread(() => {
while (true)
{
   ...

 MessagingCenter.Send<ISocket, string>(this, "new Messages", data1);

...               
});
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I am able to display messages on my UI, and I have a little confusion about when instantiating a new thread in the android project, why you used Java.Lang.Thread instead of System.Threading.Thread?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked ! if I also want to implement the socket method in my ios project, which thread API should I use? @ Elvis Xia - MSFT